# "set" command error found in tcsh with the varValue that contain curly brace

Tags: unix, tcsh

Please tell me how to resolve the Missing } error message using tcsh command.

```
%set aaa = {123 456}
Missing }.
%set aaa = '{123 456}'
echo $aaa
Missing }.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a comma:

```
set aaa = {123,456}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set `$aaa` to the string `"{123 456}"`, you need single or double quotes around the value, as in your second `set` command.

When you do `echo $aaa`, it expands to the value you assigned to it, *and then* the braces are expanded (see the csh/tcsh documentation for information on brace expansion). To avoid the brace expansion, either add double quotes:

```
echo "$aaa"
```

or use the `:q` qualifier:

```
echo $aaa:q
```